# Fluent API with multiple generic parameters and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, fluent-interface

I am trying to implement a fluent API that contains specialized derived classes and I am using the `Derived extends Base<Derived>` method to obtain `this` parameter as `Derived` from base methods, but it doesn't seem to work with multiple generic parameters, for instance:

```
public class Specialized<T> extends Base<Specialized<T>, Iterable<T>> {
    void someAMethod() {
    }
}

public class Base<ThisType extends Base<ThisType, T>, T> {
    public ThisType baseMethod() {
        return getMe();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ThisType getMe() {
        return (ThisType) this;
    }
}
```

And later use it like:

```
new Specialized().baseMethod()
                 .someAMethod();
```

But `baseMethod()` doesn't return a `Specialized` object, so I am getting this error:

> Cannot resolve method 'someAMethod()'

Comment: You're using a raw type in `new Specialized()...`, this will erase all generics, so the method will return a `Base` object, since that is it's erasure.

Comment: See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard wopsie, I was testing it as a nested class in test class, so `public` wasn't really necessary.

Comment: @JornVernee you're right, eh, how could I not notice that? Thank you!